# Is there an alternative to using ROW_NUMBER() in the recursive part of a CTE?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I am trying to produce a full Bill Of Materials explosion which shows the following:
(a) all subcomponents appear immediately after their parent/senior product
(b) the products read in the anchor part of the CTE have a level of 1
(c) the components read in the recursive part of the CTE have a level which is 1 greater than their parent's

The query works in SQL Server but fails in MySQL 8.

I have tried ways to obtain a value which is equivalent to ROW_NUMBER(), but without success. I cannot use variables as these are disallowed in CTEs.

Here is my table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bill_of_materials` (
  `product_id_snr` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `product_id_jnr` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(18,9) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.000000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id_snr`,`product_id_jnr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here is my data:

```sql
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('SNAFU', 'B-2A_ASSY', 1);
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('SNAFU', 'TMJ_TEST', 1);
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('B-2A_ASSY', 'TMJ', 1);
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('B-2A_ASSY', 'TMJ_ASSY_B', 1);
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('TMJ', 'TMJ_CP', 1);
INSERT INTO `bill_of_materials` (`product_id_snr`, `product_id_jnr`, `quantity`) VALUES ('TMJ', 'TMJ_WAFER', 1);
```

Here is the query which works in SQL Server but fails in MySQL:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE bom (sort_seq, level, product_id_snr, product_id_jnr, quantity)
AS ( SELECT CAST(CONCAT('/', LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pc.product_id_snr ASC, pc.product_id_jnr ASC), 4, '0')) AS char(4000) CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4) AS sort_seq
, 1 AS level
, pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
FROM bill_of_materials AS pc
WHERE product_id_snr='SNAFU'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONCAT(bom.sort_seq, '/', LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pc.product_id_snr ASC, pc.product_id_jnr ASC), 4, '0')) AS sort_seq
, level+1, pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
FROM bill_of_materials AS pc
INNER JOIN bom ON (pc.product_id_snr  = bom.product_id_jnr)
)
SELECT bom.* FROM bom
ORDER BY sort_seq ASC
```

The error message is "Recursive Common Table Expression 'bom' can contain neither aggregate nor window functions in recursive query block"

The expected output should be:

```
sort_seq            ;level ;product_id_snr ;product_id_jnr ;quantity
/0001               ;1     ;SNAFU          ;B-2A_ASSY      ;1
/0001/0001          ;2     ;B-2A_ASSY      ;TMJ            ;1
/0001/0002/0001     ;3     ;TMJ            ;TMJ_CP         ;1
/0001/0002/0002     ;3     ;TMJ            ;TMJ_WAFER      ;1
/0001/0003          ;2     ;B-2A_ASSY      ;TMJ_ASSY_B     ;1
/0002               ;1     ;SNAFU          ;TMJ_TEST       ;1
```

If I replace ROW_NUMBER() with product_id_jnr as in:

```sql
CONCAT(bom.sort_seq, '/', pc.product_id_jnr) AS sort_seq
```

I get the following results:

```
sort_seq            ;level ;product_id_snr ;product_id_jnr ;quantity
/0001               ;1     ;SNAFU          ;B-2A_ASSY      ;1
/0001/TMJ           ;2     ;B-2A_ASSY      ;TMJ            ;1
/0001/TMJ_ASSY_B    ;2     ;B-2A_ASSY      ;TMJ_ASSY_B     ;1
/0001/TMJ/TMJ_CP    ;3     ;TMJ            ;TMJ_CP         ;1
/0001/TMJ/TMJ_WAFER ;3     ;TMJ            ;TMJ_WAFER      ;1
/0002               ;1     ;SNAFU          ;TMJ_TEST       ;1
```

This is wrong because TMJ_ASSY_B appears in row 3 when it should be in row 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to include the columns that you want to order by into your path is correct. You just have to make sure that the separator is lexigraphically ordered before everything else (as the problem in your example is that the `_` in `TMJ_ASSY_B` comes before the `/` in `TMJ/TMJ_CP`).

If your product ids do not contain a space (ASCII 32) this would be the obvious choice, otherwise you can either use *more* spaces (more than any occurence in your data) or e.g. `char(9)`, `char(13)` or similar:

```
WITH RECURSIVE bom (sort_seq, level, product_id_snr, product_id_jnr, quantity)
AS (
  SELECT CAST(CONCAT(pc.product_id_snr, ' ', pc.product_id_jnr) 
              AS char(4000) CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4) AS sort_seq
    , 1 AS level
    , pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
  FROM bill_of_materials AS pc
  WHERE product_id_snr='SNAFU'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONCAT(bom.sort_seq, ' ', pc.product_id_snr, ' ',
           pc.product_id_jnr) AS sort_seq
    , level+1, pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
  FROM bill_of_materials AS pc
  INNER JOIN bom ON (pc.product_id_snr  = bom.product_id_jnr)
)
SELECT bom.* FROM bom
ORDER BY sort_seq ASC
```

returns a correctly placed `TMJ_ASSY_B` in the 5th row:

```
+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
|                  sort_seq                    | level  | product_id_snr  | product_id_jnr  | quantity |
+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
| SNAFU B-2A_ASSY                              |     1  | SNAFU           | B-2A_ASSY       |        1 |
| SNAFU B-2A_ASSY B-2A_ASSY TMJ                |     2  | B-2A_ASSY       | TMJ             |        1 |
| SNAFU B-2A_ASSY B-2A_ASSY TMJ TMJ TMJ_CP     |     3  | TMJ             | TMJ_CP          |        1 |
| SNAFU B-2A_ASSY B-2A_ASSY TMJ TMJ TMJ_WAFER  |     3  | TMJ             | TMJ_WAFER       |        1 |
| SNAFU B-2A_ASSY B-2A_ASSY TMJ_ASSY_B         |     2  | B-2A_ASSY       | TMJ_ASSY_B      |        1 |
| SNAFU TMJ_TEST                               |     1  | SNAFU           | TMJ_TEST        |        1 |
+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Both `pc.product_id_snr` and `pc.product_id_jnr` are used, to match your original order `(ORDER BY pc.product_id_snr ASC, pc.product_id_jnr ASC)`. In case those two columns are not unique, the primary key can be appended to make the order well-defined (although in your case, it is already the primary key).

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I have tried it on a BOM which has over 200 entries and 5 levels, and the output is 100% correct. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have received the following answer from someone at MySQL:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE bill_of_m_with_nr AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc.product_id_snr ORDER BY pc.product_id_snr ASC, pc.product_id_jnr ASC) AS child_nr FROM bill_of_materials pc)
, bom (sort_seq, level, product_id_snr, product_id_jnr, quantity)
AS ( SELECT CAST(CONCAT('/', LPAD(pc.child_nr, 4, '0')) AS char(4000)) AS sort_seq
, 1 AS level
, pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
FROM bill_of_m_with_nr AS pc
WHERE product_id_snr='SNAFU'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONCAT(bom.sort_seq, '/', LPAD(pc.child_nr, 4, '0')) AS sort_seq
, level+1, pc.product_id_snr, pc.product_id_jnr, pc.quantity
FROM bill_of_m_with_nr AS pc
INNER JOIN bom ON (pc.product_id_snr  = bom.product_id_jnr)
)
SELECT bom.* FROM bom
ORDER BY sort_seq ASC;
```

I found no description of this in the documentation, but it does work.